# jQuery vertical animation does not work in Firefox (Chrome is fine)

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, animation

Mozilla Firefox is not animating the vertical animation on the site I am currently developing.

Live:
http://daft-tech.net/

**Explanation:**

When you start typing somewhere on the site the search function will show in the fixed header and let you search what you want. It animates with jQuery, but in Firefox the Input and search results won't fade vertically. They just jump to the left. Everything else is fine. In Chrome they fade smoothly out of the screen.

Is it my fault or is it caused by jQuery?
Is it my stylesheet concurrenting with something in jQuery?

Update: I checked everything and every animation I checked worked in firefox, except the vertical sliding ($("#search").animate({ left:"+=50px" }, 100, null);)

Code:

```
var searchState = false;

function searchHide() {
    if (searchState) {
        $("#search").hide(500);
        searchState = false;
    }
}

function searchShow() {
    if (!searchState) {
        $("#searchResults").hide(300);
        $("#search").show(100);
        $("#searchInput").focus();
        searchState = true;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="search">
    <input name="searchInput" id="searchInput" onkeyup="searchKeyPress(event);" style="border: 1px ridge white; background-color: black; color: white;" />
    <div id="searchResults"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search {
    max-width: 1050px;
    margin: 3px auto;  
    background-color: black;
}
#search input {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#searchResults {
    color: white;
}
#searchResults p {
    padding: 3px;
}
#searchResults a {
    color: white;
}
#searchResults span {
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding:0px 4px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: If I hold down the Backspace or start mashing it, the animation will just happen over and over again. You could try removing focus from the search box before the animation. (Chrome)

Comment: I see nothing on that page, you should post the code and associated markup, not some random link.

Comment: Yeah I am currently fixing that (that the animation repeats. I don't know why the page is empty for you Mark) ^^

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The site has no content. He is only talking about the search function, yet you're right, relevant code should be included.

Comment: I see NO search function - or anything to "type in" on the linked page in IE8 test...voting to close per that and my other comment.

Comment: I am currently trying to add code to the post but you have to cry -.-

Comment: And yes, it is currently incompatible to IE8.

Comment: @th3falc0n For the backspace thing, I suggest using the [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) method.

Comment: Can I ask why the Search function wouldn't be visible in the first place? How would a user know to just start typing that it would produce a search box ?

Comment: @DJDavid98: i fixed that just a second ago.

Comment: @Ryan: for compatibility and accessibility reasons there will be a button to open it AND a second more advanced search.

Comment: @th3falc0n Tried using any animations other than the simple `.hide(100)`? Do they work?

Comment: And can somebody please say me why you want to close this question?

Comment: I don't see the problem described. Works for me on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: For me in firefox the textbox and search results are not sliding to the left when search form closes. In Chrome they do.